# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: pdo, mariadb

Most answers were that it would be a right issue. But I assume not in this case, because mysql-connection still worked.

I am trying to connect to a mariadb10, which was on a server in my network
I am trying to connect from my localhost.

If I try in my terminal:

```
myuser@mylocalComputer ~ $ mysql -h myserver -P 3307 -u mydbuser -pmyconfidentalpassword
```

everything works fine!!

But If I try to connect by php scrypt by pdo I get the error:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql: host=myserver:3307;dbname=mydbname';
$username = 'mydbuser';
$password = 'myconfidentalpassword';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
   if(! $dbh ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'select * from foo;';
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not select data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   echo "Synced data successfully\n";
   mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

The Error was:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'mydbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/myuser/Projekte/Hibiscus_extend/Hib_Nightly_sync.php:8

> Stack trace:
>
> > /home/myuser/Projekte/Hibiscus_extend/Hib_Nightly_sync.php(8):
> >     PDO->__construct('mysql: host=myse...', 'mydbuser',
> >     'myconfidentalpassword', Array)
> >  
> >  {main}   thrown in
> >     /home/myuser/Projekte/Hibiscus_extend/Hib_Nightly_sync.php on line 8

What did I do wrong, and where?

Answer (score 1):

Oh Oh Oh!
I found the solution!
The reason for the connection problem were just the empty spaces in $dsn

Wrong:
$dsn = 'mysql: host=myserver:3307;dbname=mydbname';

works fine
$dsn = 'mysql:host=myserver:3307;dbname=mydbname';